# Early stopping and learning rate schedule based on custom metric in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, object-detection

I have an object detection model in Keras and want to monitor and control my training based on mean average precision (mAP) calculated on the validation set.

I have ported code from [tensorflow-models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) into my scripts that runs the evaluation using the model and data provided. It is not implemented as a Keras metric though, but as a standalone class:

```
evaluation = SSDEvaluation(model, data, data_size)
mAP = evaluation.evaluate()
```

I am completely fine with having it like this. Indeed, I do not want it to be calculated for training batches, as it will slow down the training.

My question is: How to re-use `ReduceLROnPlateau` and `EarlyStopping` callbacks based on this metric being calculated after each epoch?

Comment: You can try using LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=mAp) [link] (https://keras.io/callbacks/#lambdacallback) hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with using a [LambdaCallback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#lambdacallback) that updates your `logs` object:

Assuming that your `evaluation.evaluate()` returns a dictionary like `{'val/mAP': value}`, you can do like this:

```
eval_callback = LambdaCallback(
     on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: logs.update(evaluation.evaluate())
)
```

The trick here is that the `logs` will be passed further to other callbacks, so they can directly access the value:

```
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val/mAP', min_delta=0.0, patience=10, verbose=1, mode='max')
```

It will automagically appear in the `CSVLogger` and any other callback. But note that `eval_callback` must be prior to any callback using the value in the callbacks list:

```
callbacks = [eval_callback, early_stopping]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is `SSDEvaluation` but if any mean average preccision calculation without overhead is acceptable, I propose the following method using keras [callbacks](https://keras.io/callbacks/).

The main idea that you wish oto use two callbacls - `EarlyStopping` and `ReduceLROnPlateau` - both acting on the epoch end and monitoring a `loss` or `metric` value. They get this value from the `logs` argument of the [method](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L330)

```
 def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
     """Called at the end of an epoch.
     ...
     """
```

- sending actual *map* to logs value we force this method and all callbacks which gets accuracy value from logs to use it. Callbcaks pick the value from here ([this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L837) ine int the code - early stopping, and [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L1374) one for the Reduce LR).
So, we should "fake" logs for both callbacks. I guess this is not ideal, but working solution.

This classes inherit from the callbacks and calculating the *map* value, also they avoiding re-calculation of *map* via shared object `Hub`.

```
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score

import keras
from keras.callbacks import Callback, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau


class MAPHub:
    def __init__(self):
        self.map_value = None
```

- it's just hub to share the *map* value. May be it causes some side-effects. You can try to avoid using it.

```
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
    """self just a callbcak instance"""
    if self.last_metric_for_epoch == epoch:
        map_ = self.hub.map_value
    else:
        prediction = self.model.predict(self._data, verbose=1)
        map_ = average_precision_score(self._target, prediction)
        self.hub.map_value = map_
        self.last_metric_for_epoch = epoch
```

- this funtion calcylates and shares the *map*

```
class EarlyStoppingByMAP(EarlyStopping):
    def __init__(self, data, target, hub, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        data, target - values and target for the map calculation
        hub - shared object to store _map_ value 
        *args, **kwargs for the super __init__
        """
        # I've set monitor to 'acc' here, because you're interested in metric, not loss
        super(EarlyStoppingByMAP, self).__init__(monitor='acc', *args, **kwargs)
        self._target = target
        self._data = data 
        self.last_metric_for_epoch = -1
        self.hub = hub

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        """
        epoch is the number of epoch, logs is a dict logs with 'loss' value 
        and metric 'acc' values
        """
        on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)      
        logs['acc'] = self.hub.map_value  # "fake" metric with calculated value
        print('Go callback from the {}, logs: \n{}'.format(EarlyStoppingByMAP.__name__, logs))
        super(EarlyStoppingByMAP, self).on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)  # works as a callback fn


class ReduceLROnPlateauByMAP(ReduceLROnPlateau):
    def __init__(self, data, target, hub, *args, **kwargs):
        # the same as in previous
        # I've set monitor to 'acc' here, because you're interested in metric, not loss
        super(ReduceLROnPlateauByMAP, self).__init__(monitor='acc', *args, **kwargs)
        self._target = target
        self._data = data 
        self.last_metric_for_epoch = -1
        self.hub = hub


    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
        logs['acc'] = self.hub.map_value   # "fake" metric with calculated value
        print('Go callback from the {}, logs: \n{}'.format(ReduceLROnPlateau.__name__, logs))
        super(ReduceLROnPlateauByMAP, self).on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)  # works as a callback fn
```

- **NB** do not use the `monitor` argument in constructor! You should use 'acc', parameter is already set to the correct value.

Some tests:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
import numpy as np

(X_tr, y_tr), (X_te, y_te) = mnist.load_data()
X_tr = (X_tr / 255.).reshape((60000, 784))
X_te = (X_te / 255.).reshape((10000, 784))


def binarize_labels(y):
    y_bin = np.zeros((len(y), len(np.unique(y)))) 
    y_bin[range(len(y)), y] = 1
    return y_bin

y_train_bin, y_test_bin = binarize_labels(y_tr), binarize_labels(y_te)


inp = Input(shape=(784,))
x = Dense(784, activation='relu')(inp)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
out = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

- a simple "test suite". Now go fit it:

```
hub = MAPHub()  # instentiate a hub
# I will use default params except patience as example, set it to 1 and 5
early_stop = EarlyStoppingByMAP(X_te, y_test_bin, hub, patience=1)  # Patience is EarlyStopping's param
reduce_lt = ReduceLROnPlateauByMAP(X_te, y_test_bin, hub, patience=5)  # Patience is ReduceLR's param

history = model.fit(X_tr, y_train_bin, epochs=10, callbacks=[early_stop, reduce_lt])
Out:
Epoch 1/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 12s 207us/step - loss: 0.1815
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 59us/step
Go callback from the EarlyStoppingByMAP, logs: 
{'loss': 0.18147853660446903, 'acc': 0.9934216252519924}
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 40us/step
Go callback from the ReduceLROnPlateau, logs: 
{'loss': 0.18147853660446903, 'acc': 0.9934216252519924}
Epoch 2/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 12s 197us/step - loss: 0.0784
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 40us/step
Go callback from the EarlyStoppingByMAP, logs: 
{'loss': 0.07844233275586739, 'acc': 0.9962269038764738}
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step
Go callback from the ReduceLROnPlateau, logs: 
{'loss': 0.07844233275586739, 'acc': 0.9962269038764738}
Epoch 3/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 12s 197us/step - loss: 0.0556
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 40us/step
Go callback from the EarlyStoppingByMAP, logs: 
{'loss': 0.05562876497630107, 'acc': 0.9972085346550085}
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 40us/step
Go callback from the ReduceLROnPlateau, logs: 
{'loss': 0.05562876497630107, 'acc': 0.9972085346550085}
Epoch 4/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 12s 198us/step - loss: 0.0389
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step
Go callback from the EarlyStoppingByMAP, logs: 
{'loss': 0.0388911374788188, 'acc': 0.9972696414934574}
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step
Go callback from the ReduceLROnPlateau, logs: 
{'loss': 0.0388911374788188, 'acc': 0.9972696414934574}
Epoch 5/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 12s 197us/step - loss: 0.0330
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step
Go callback from the EarlyStoppingByMAP, logs: 
{'loss': 0.03298293751536124, 'acc': 0.9959456176387349}
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step
Go callback from the ReduceLROnPlateau, logs: 
{'loss': 0.03298293751536124, 'acc': 0.9959456176387349}
```

Ok, looks like at least an early stopping works. I guess, `ReduceLROnPlateau` to, because they use the same logs and similar logic - if there're apropriate parameters were set.

If you don't want to use sklearn function, but `SSDEvaluation` (I just can't find what it is) - tou can easily adopt the `on_epoch_method` function to deal with this evaluation function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Subclassing every callback looks a substantial overhead though. Maybe there is a simpler solution?

Comment: Probably yes - using `Lambda` Callback / monkey-pathcing a callback. At least `on_batch_epoch` method overriding and providing test date is required. This callbacks almost have desired behaviour, and despite change it is not so easy - but write a callback from scratch much more harder.

Comment: Also you can define [custom metric](https://keras.io/metrics/) written in keras/tensorflow (look at the bottom of the page) - but I wrote my solution assumnig that this is not acceptable for some reason and you're planning to use some non-keras metric. That case, I don't know an easier way. Otherwise, ofc, it's possibly to define a custom mean average precision as described in docs

Comment: So, there are callbacks only leftto choose. If too tedious override a lot of callbacks the same way, may be some higher-level "overrider" factory is acceptable solution?